# SQL: Showing the matched ANY value in the results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SELECT with an ANY array like

```
SELECT name FROM t_example WHERE name LIKE ANY('{%boo%,%lala%}');
```

So my wish is to get a furhter column in the result, where I can see which value of the array matched. In this example very useless, but if one result has the name "Abool", an extra column should have the "boo" from the array in it.

Is there a way you can get to the ANY-result?

Like (Pseudocode)

```
SELECT name, matched FROM t_example WHERE name LIKE ANY('{%boo%,%lala%}') AS matched;
```

I want to have a resultset like

```
name      matched
Abool     %boo%
Valala    %lala%
```

Comment: I don't understand.  You are using `= ANY`, so `name` matches the result.

Comment: I want a result set like:: name: Abool, machted: %boo%

Comment: . . Your code is not using `LIKE` so you are not getting a wildcard match.

Comment: Youre right, it has to be name LIKE ANY(), but how can I read or get what has matched?

Answer (score 0):

Join two table.

The second table has "wildcard match pattern" column.

Use LIKE operator in JOIN condition.

```
SELECT 
string.name,
match.matched 
FROM ( values ('Abool'), ('Valala') ) AS string (name)
JOIN ( VALUES ('%boo%'), ('%lala%') ) AS match(matched) ON string.name LIKE match.matched
```

Comment: Thank you, but here you are hardcoding the names as values, not what I need. When I get my results I want to know which values I asked for, matched the names in the db. I am searching for "%boo%" and as result I want to see that "%boo%" in an extra column.

Comment: Join two table. The second table  has "wildcard match pattern" column.  Use LIKE operator in JOIN condition.

Comment: ```LANG-SQL SELECT string.name, match.matched FROM (
values
('Abool'),
('Valala')
) AS string (name) 
JOIN
(
VALUES
('%boo%'),
('%lala%')
) AS match(matched)
ON string.name LIKE match.matched```

Comment: Exactly what I searched for!!! Thank you, can you add it as answer so that I can flag it as solved??

Comment: @Frbr no problem